# Dynamic Programming technique for solving problems

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Is it possible to solve any Dynamic Programming problem using recursion+memoization instead of using tabulation/iteration? Or there are some problems where it is must to use tabulation/iteration.

Also can we obtain the same time complexity when solving any problem using recursion+memoization ( I know space complexity differs and also recursion overhead cost exists).

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you’re asking. In general, the generality of computation trivially implies that every iterative algorithm can be rewritten using recursion. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: I know what you are saying. What I am asking is that can all dynamic programming problems be solved using recursive approach or there are some problems like subset sum which needs to be solve using tabulation to avoid NP caused due to recursive approach.

Comment: But using recursion does not imply not using tabulation. Both can be used in combination.

Comment: Yes and yes (as long as you use memoization with `O(1)`-time access). The main difference between recursive and iterative approach is that in the latter case you need to know the order in which you process subproblems. So in case of recursive approach, you do the same operations, but in a different order.

Comment: @Konrad RudolphThat is a different point. I want to know that using only recursion+memoization can we solve all the problems of dynamic programming.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  the process of filling table in recursive approach is generally called memoization and tabulation is the term used when you are solving using iterative solution

Comment: @Abhishek I’m well aware, and that’s not what I meant: memoisation is (in common terminology) mutating something outside the scope of the function. I was talking about passing the data recursively.

Comment: @Lucas subset sum IS NP complete regardless of the method. There is a classic reduction from 3SAT to subset sum discussed in many textbooks. The iterative solution is O(nS) where n is the number of items and S is the sum but it does not make it polynomial since the input size is the number of bits needed to represent S i.e. S~ 2^b

Comment: @HikmatFarhat So does this means that whichever method we use (recursion+memoization or tabulation) there will be same time complexity for subset sum problem? And will it be true for other problems also that both the methods give the same time complexity? Please explain.

Comment: @Lucas Asymptotically yes they are the same if memoization can be done in O(1). In practice it depends on the problem instance. Sometimes recursion+memoization is faster because it doesn't need to solve ALL subproblems to find a solution like the tabulation.

Comment: Let me qualify the above answer. In some NP complete problems tricks can be used to reduce the complexity but no one has been able to reduce them to polynomial. for example solving 3SAT by brute force is O(2^n) but using a simple trick in backtracking can reduce it to O(1.8^n). Obviously the second method is better even asymptotically but it is still exponential. So going back to the subset sum, asymptotically both approaches are the same because they are using the same recursive relation between subproblems. One solves bottom up and the other top down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every ***Dynamic Programming problem can be expressed as recurrence relation*** which can be **solved using recursion+memoization** which can be **converted into tabulation+iteration**.

When you solve a DP problem using tabulation you solve the problem **bottom up**, typically by filling up an n-dimensional table. Based on the results in the table, the solution to the original problem is then computed.

When you solve a DP problem using memoization, you do it by maintaining a map of already solved sub problems. You do it **top down** in the sense that you solve the "top" problem first (which typically recurses down to solve the sub-problems).

The time complexity of a DP problem which uses tabulation+iteration is the same as an converted equivalent and correct memoization+recursion version of the solution. It is usually easy to find the time complexity in an tabulation+iteration method. On the other hand, memoization+recursion version of DP solution is more intuitive and readable.

Comment: Is it possible to solve subset sum problem using recursion+ memoization in polynomial complexity? Someone said to me  that tabulation is used to get solution in polynomial time complexity not recursion.

Comment: Every recursive function/solution can be converted into an equivalent iterative version and vice-versa. Generally recursive solutions have more space-complexity but about the same time-complexity. I haven't much experience about subset-sum problem in particular but with the information mentioned above, I can say that its possible to solve the problem using recursion+memoization (as long as the memory doesn't become the bottleneck)

Comment: @Lucas with few quick searches online, I can see that there's no truly polynomial time-complexity solution available for subset-sum problem. Also, I can see that most online sources mention the time-complexity of both versions to be about the same for that problem.

Comment: Please see this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/?ref=rp before tabulation it is mentioning about NP for recursive approach.

Comment: @Lucas recursive approach is not the same as recursion+memoization. In simple naive recursion you will be calculating same sub-problems again and again whereas in the latter you will not. In the recursive approach mentioned in the link you posted, there's no memoization used and hence the higher time-complexity

Comment: Can you please tell how can I write memoization code for that. I would be extremely thankful. I tried for 2 days but wasn't able to apply properly therefore that resulted in asking this question that can every problem be solved using .....

Comment: You can try submitting here https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem/0 .

Comment: @Lucas I can see that there's a top-down approach posted in the comment secion of  the link that you mentioned above

Comment: Can you please write a working code. Take your time. Just add memoization in that code.

Comment: Here's another link for memoization approach - https://www.techiedelight.com/subset-sum-problem/ . As a side note, always keep in mind that a DP will always have a recurrence relation which is why every DP can be solved using recursive DP approach. A DP should ideally be solved using brute recursion, evolved into a memoized recursion which can be converted into iterative tabulation solution. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The only thing I would add to this excellent answer is that with a bottom up solution you can often figure out when you're done with data and can throw it away.  Therefore memory usage is often better with bottom up than top down.